# Is the Laplacian a vector or a scalar?

Tags: vector-analysis

Need to prove $\operatorname{div}(\nabla u)=\nabla ^2 u$ where $u=g(x,y,z)$

The RHS is the Lapacian which we were told is a vector. But $\nabla u=(g_x,g_y,g_z)$ and the divergence of that is $g_{xx}+g_{yy}+g_{zz}$ which is not a vector. I don't get how it can equate then...

Comment: The Laplacian takes a scalar valued function and gives back a scalar valued function. If the function is vector valued, then its Laplacian is vector valued. I abhor the del squared notation that you've used for this reason. It's completely incorrect notation and it can be confusing.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are saying. We were told that if we have a differentiable scalar field $u$, the Laplacian of $u$ is $$\nabla ^2 u = \bigg( \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x^2},\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial y^2},\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial z^2} \bigg)$$

Comment: That is not correct at all. What you wrote as the Laplacian in your post is correct.

Comment: Clearly my lecturer wrote the completely wrong thing then. Thanks.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Would it interest you to know that $\nabla^2 = \nabla \cdot \nabla + \nabla \wedge \nabla$ (which is completely analogous to the vector square $\vec a^2 = \vec a\cdot \vec a + \vec a \wedge \vec a$) in geometric algebra/ calculus?  So at least in that system, it makes a lot of sense to me.  (Note that if you have equality of mixed partials, then $\nabla \wedge \nabla F = 0$ for any multivector field $F$ and thus this reduces to the regular expression for $\nabla^2$)

Comment: @Bye_World I'm aware of this but when $\nabla^2$ is written, it is usually meant as $\Delta$, i.e. $\nabla\cdot\nabla$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "Laplacian" is an operator that can operate on both scalar fields and vector fields.  The operator on a scalar can be written,

$$\nabla^2 \{\} = \nabla \cdot (\nabla \{\})$$

which will produce another scalar field.

The operator on a vector can be expressed as

$$\nabla^2 \{\} = \nabla (\nabla \cdot \{\})\,\,-\nabla \times (\nabla \times \{\})$$

which will produce another vector field.

In Cartesian coordinates, both operators can be written

$$\nabla^2 \{\} = \frac{\partial^2 \{\}}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 \{\}}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2 \{\}}{\partial z^2}$$

where it is evident that operation on a scalar (vector) field transforms into a scalar (vector) field.

Comment: I saw once that the laplacian was written like $\Delta \{ \}$, is this true?

Comment: @snowman Yes, some use the notation "$\Delta$" to represent the Laplacian.

Comment: What about vector fields in dimension more than 3?

Comment: @user5y292 The OP's question is about the operator on $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same question. In the last equation $\nabla^2\{\}$ acts on a 3-dimensional vector and returns a sum which is a scalar. So it seems that the operation on a vector returns a scalar, which doesn't agree with your last sentence. What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 1):

Lapacian of an ***Nth*** Rank Tensor is another ***Nth*** Rank Tensor. This means Lapacian of a **Scalar Field** is **another Scalar Field**. Laplacian of **Vector Field** is **another Vector Field** and so on.

Comment: so the laplacian of a matrix field is a matrix field